# SharePoint 2013 CSOM C# Create document with versions keeping Editor/Modified

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-2016

currently I'm working on a tool for migrating SP2013 to SP2016 (using ShareGate is no option Management says :/)
What I'm doing is looping thorugh all Websites in SP2013 and perform a backup in form of a json, keeping all lists, items, documents etc. together.

My export structure looks like this:

```
structure.json // contains a tree view of webs and their subwebs
123-456-789-000/ // this is a web
|-web.json // contains all the web data like lists, items etc.
|-lists/
|--listname/
|---document.txt
|---...
```

Currently I'm stuck with importing documents - more specific with their versions.
I'm trying to import a document, which is no problem at all, but creating a version needs a checkout/checkin cycle.
The checkin overwrites my editor and modified date - causing the farmadmin to be the last editor of all my documents (which should be the user who did it in SP2013).

After some googling I've found **ValidateUpdateListItem**, but that leads to a checkin (which keeps the editor) but only creates a minor version - I need a major version though.

In SSOM I would impersonate using **new SPSite(url, userToken)** and perform the checkin inside the user context - but that's no option in CSOM.

Anyone faced this issue, or am I on the wrong way?

Comment: You should be able to execute the office check in / checkout function to simulate that, last time I dealt with that migration.